# Material UI withStyles in an NPM package causes errors when used through npm link

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, higher-order-components, npm-package

I'm trying to locally build the [`oodt_fm_plugin`](https://github.com/apache/oodt/tree/development/react-components/oodt_fm_plugin) NPM package and link it locally to the [`oodt_opsui_sample_app`](https://github.com/apache/oodt/tree/development/react-components/oodt_opsui_sample_app). However, when I'm trying to do that, the following error is thrown in the browser.

> Error: Minified React error #321; visit
> https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full
> message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and
> additional helpful warnings.

The error goes away if I remove the `withStyles` HOC from the components in `oodt_fm_plugin`, but I want to preserve it for the material UI styles.

React components in the `oodt_fm_plugin` have been exported as follows. ( This plugin can be viewed at https://github.com/apache/oodt/tree/development/react-components/oodt_fm_plugin. )

`export default withStyles(styles)(Product);`

What I tried to overcome this are as follows, but none of those solved the issue.

1. Making `react` and `react-dom` packages in the plugin, dev dependencies
2. Adding the following snippet to the `webpack.config.js` of the plugin.

```js
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve('node_modules'), 'node_modules'],
    },
```

Can someone point me in the right direction so that I can set up both `oodt_fm_plugin` and `oodt_ui_sample_app` correctly in local dev environment? Helpful advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to solve the problem, after trying for several days. As I found out, it was not a problem with material ui, but with the Create React App. This [Github issue comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-496383268) helped me to solve my problem.

For extra clarity, I will quote the issue comment in this answer itself, so that it will remain here even if the comment gets deleted.

> ^ Ok, the solution I went for to solve this for create-react-app is to
> use react-app-rewired and customize-cra.
>
> Here is my config-overrides.js :
>
> ```
> const {
>     override,
>     addWebpackAlias,   } = require("customize-cra");
>
> const path = require('path'); 
>
> module.exports = override( 
>     addWebpackAlias({
>         react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
>     }) )
> ```
>
> Example project: https://github.com/dwjohnston/material-ui-hooks-issue/tree/master

Then, modify the `start` script as follows.

```js
"start": "react-app-rewired start"
```